# Paypal Billing Agreement Auto-Accept Payments?

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn, paypal-sandbox, paypal-subscriptions, paypal-rest-sdk

I have successfully created and activated a Billing Plan via Paypal's Rest API. The user is charged the correct amount, in the correct intervals. But I need to accept each payment manually at my seller account. How can I set it to auto accept all incoming payments?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe it is caused by the payment review setting in your sandbox seller account. If payment review is on, then you will need to accept (or deny) every transaction manually. Here's how to turn it off:

1. Log into https://developer.paypal.com
2. Click Dashboard
3. Click Accounts (under Sandbox section)
4. Click on the seller sandbox account you used in the transaction
5. Click Profile
6. Go to Settings tab, and select Off for 'Payment Review'

Comment: Yes, that was the problem. Thanks for your help!

Comment: No problem. Im glad that I can help